# Extracting Timestamp from producer message

Tags: java, apache-kafka-streams

I really need help! 
I can't **extract the timestamp for a message sent by a producer**. In my project I work with Json, I have a class in which I define the keys and one in which I define the values ​​of the message that I will send via a producer on a "Raw" topic. I have 2 other classes that do the same thing for the output message that my consumer will read on the topic called "Tdt". In the main class KafkaStreams.java I define the stream and map the keys and values. Starting Kafka locally, I start a producer who writes a message on the "raw" topic with keys and values, then on another shell the consumer starts reading the exit message on the "tdt" topic. How do I get the event timestamp? I need to know the timestamp in which the message was sent by the producer. Do I need a TimestampExtractor? 
Here is my main class kafkastreams (my application works great, I just need the timestamp)

```
  @Bean("app1StreamTopology") 
        public KStream<LibAssIbanRawKey, LibAssIbanRawValue> kStream() throws ParseException {
    JsonSerde<Dwsitspr4JoinValue> Dwsitspr4JoinValueSerde = new JsonSerde<>(Dwsitspr4JoinValue.class);

            KStream<LibAssIbanRawKey, LibAssIbanRawValue> stream = defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder.stream(inputTopic);

            stream.peek((k,v) -> logger.info("Debug3 Chiave descrizione -> ({})",v.getCATRAPP()));


            GlobalKTable<Integer, Dwsitspr4JoinValue> categoriaRapporto = defaultKafkaStreamsBuilder
                    .globalTable(temptiptopicname, 
                            Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), Dwsitspr4JoinValueSerde)
                            //                      .withOffsetResetPolicy(Topology.AutoOffsetReset.EARLIEST)
                            );

            logger.info("Debug3 Chiave descrizione -> ({})",categoriaRapporto.toString()) ;
            stream.peek((k,v) -> logger.info("Debug4 Chiave descrizione -> ({})",v.getCATRAPP()) );

            stream
            .join(categoriaRapporto, (k, v) -> v.getCATRAPP(), (valueStream, valueGlobalKtable) -> {

                // Value mapping
                LibAssIbanTdtValue newValue = new LibAssIbanTdtValue();
                newValue.setDescrizioneRidottaCodiceCategoriaDelRapporto(valueGlobalKtable.getDescrizioneRidotta());
                newValue.setDescrizioneEstesaCodiceCategoriaDelRapporto(valueGlobalKtable.getDescrizioneEstesa()); 
                newValue.setIdentificativo(valueStream.getAUD_CCID());
.
.
.//Other Value Mapped
.
.
    .map((key, value) -> {
                // Key mapping
                LibAssIbanTdtKey newKey = new LibAssIbanTdtKey();
                newKey.setData(dtf.format(localDate));
                newKey.setIdentificatoreUnivocoDellaRigaDiTabella(key.getTABROWID());

                return KeyValue.pair(newKey, value);
            }).to(outputTopic, Produced.with(new JsonSerde<>(LibAssIbanTdtKey.class), new JsonSerde<>(LibAssIbanTdtValue.class)));
            return stream;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/faq.html#accessing-record-metadata-such-as-topic-partition-and-offset-information

Comment: The default timestamp extractor get the message timestamp and you can access it via `context.timestamp()` in a `Processor` or `Transformer`.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need a TimestampExtractor.

```java
public class YourTimestampExtractor implements TimestampExtractor {


    @Override
    public long extract(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> consumerRecord, long l) {

        // do whatever you want with the timestamp available with consumerRecord.timestamp()
        ...

        // return here the timestamp you want to use (here default)
        return consumerRecord.timestamp();
    }
}
```

You'll need to tell kafka stream what extractor to use under the key `StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_TIMESTAMP_EXTRACTOR_CLASS_CONFIG`

Comment: The default timestamp extractor does exactly what you describe. There is no need to implement a custom one. Cf. https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/ExtractRecordMetadataTimestamp.java

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax How can we see the timestamp without that ? If I want for example to print timestamp when a message is consumed.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax The question was about extracting the timestamp, and that's what I do personally. Is there a better way to achieve that ?

Comment: See my comment on the question. You would use `builder.stream(...).transformValues(...)` (or `transform()`) and access the timestamp via `context.timestamp()` -- the timestamp extractor should be stateless and should not have any side-effects. -- The extractor should not do any processing.